# Error with FormData.entries() in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to convert FormData to simple JSON format such as {“val1” :1 , “val2” : 3} to send to API via fetch(). But, currently FormData is a multi array

I get error **entries() is not a function** error

```
    const {email, password, fname} = this.state;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('fname', fname);

    this.setState({spinner: true});

    let jsonObject = {};

    for (const [key, value]  of formData.entries()) {
        jsonObject[key] = value;
    }
```

Comment: Please how do you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `formData.getParts()`, eg:

```js
let jsonObject = {};

for (const part of formData.getParts()) {
    jsonObject[part.fieldName] = part.string;
}
```